# how to make a string matrix in C

Tags: c

The matrix X is:

```
aa bb cc
dd ee ff
gg hh ii
```

and can be indexed as X[0][1]

my question is how to represent a string matrix in C?

I know char ***matrix, but I don't know the details

Comment: what exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: I don't know how to represent a string matrix in C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string is represented in C as an array of chars, so actually this is a three-dimensional matrix:

```
char string_matrix[ROWS][COLUMNS][STRING_LENGTH]
```

or

```
char*** string_matrix
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this? I use two dimensional array which contains pointer to char.

```
#define ROW 3
#define COL 3
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, j;
    char *matrix[ROW][COL] = {
        {"aa", "bb", "cc"},
        {"dd", "ee", "ff"},
        {"gg", "hh", "ii"},
    };

    for(i = 0; i < ROW; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < COL; j++){
            printf("matrix[%d][%d] is %s\n", i, j, matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```